# Setting different resident heap size and total swapped-out virtual memory size in Java

Tags: java, virtual-memory, java-memory-model

Is there a way in Java to set the resident heap size to say 2GB (using `-Xmx`) but the total virtual memory size to something larger, e.g. 16GB? i.e. Java would only keep 2GB in RAM but 16GB would be addressable and swapped out to disk.

Principally I want to be able to map more than the `-Xmx` limit of files at once into the virtual address space, without it counting towards the heap limit (I think all file mappings count towards the heap limit?), but also having the ability to limit the resident size while swapping out to disk if necessary would be useful.

Comment: this is exactly what happens now? `-Xms` is always pre-touched and the diff to `-Xmx` is virtual. Also look at the `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch`. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, that's the answer I was looking for. Thank you!